# exchangelib get task from task queryset MIME conversion is not supported for this item

Tags: python-3.x, exchangelib

I am trying to access an object 
through a queryset created with exchangelib however I get an error MIME CONVERSION IS NOT SUPPORTED FOR THIS ITEM, I don't know what it means. I have tried the same code with calendar items and I have no problem whatsoever. thanks

```
from exchangelib import Account, Credentials, DELEGATE

credentials = Credentials(username='BUREAU\\pepe', password='pepe')

pepe_account = Account(
    primary_smtp_address='pepe@office.com',
    credentials=credentials,
    autodiscover=True,
    access_type=DELEGATE)

tasks = pepe_account.tasks.filter()
print(tasks) -- Works
for task in tasks:
    print(task)
```

The iteration fails, instead of print(task) I also tried pass and I get the same message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    for task in tasks:
  File "/home/pepe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/exchangelib/queryset.py", line 197, in __iter__
    for val in result_formatter(self._query()):
  File "/home/pepe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/exchangelib/queryset.py", line 272, in _as_items
    for i in iterable:
  File "/home/pepe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/exchangelib/account.py", line 393, in fetch
    for i in GetItem(account=self).call(items=ids, additional_fields=additional_fields, shape=IdOnly):
  File "/home/pepe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/exchangelib/services.py", line 456, in _pool_requests
    for elem in elems:
  File "/home/pepe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/exchangelib/services.py", line 283, in _get_elements_in_response
    container_or_exc = self._get_element_container(message=msg, name=self.element_container_name)
  File "/home/pepe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/exchangelib/services.py", line 256, in _get_element_container
    self._raise_errors(code=response_code, text=msg_text, msg_xml=msg_xml)
  File "/home/pepe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/exchangelib/services.py", line 273, in _raise_errors
    raise vars(errors)[code](text)
exchangelib.errors.ErrorUnsupportedMimeConversion: MIME conversion is not supported for this item type.
```

Comment: There was a similar error reported in https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/266 You could try to not fetch the `mime_content` field, as suggested. To find the problematic item, you could do `for task in tasks.only('subject'): print(task.subject); task.refresh()`. This will print the task subjects until it hits the failing task.